# Unable to populate JSON correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of checkboxes and when I check each checkbox I want to update the JSON accordingly, and this is what the object structure should look like

```
{
  classification: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}
```

However, it's unable to push to the array properly, so I'm wondering if I'm using the spread syntax incorrectly.

```
const [ filters, setFilters ] = useState({});

const classifications = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const selectFilter = (filter, selectedFilter) => {
  setFilters({...filters, ...{ [filter]: selectedFilter }});
};


classifications.map(classification => (
  <div>
   <Checkbox
     onChange={() => selectFilter('classification', classification)}
   />
   <div>
   { classification }
   </div>
  </div>
))
```

Comment: Try with setFilters({...filters, [filter]: selectedFilter });

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code should be as follows:

```
const [ filters, setFilters ] = useState({});

const classifications = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const selectFilter = (filter, selectedFilter) => {
  setFilters({ [filter]: [...classifications,  selectedFilter ]});
};
```

Comment: Why should each entry, contain all other entries